# who is $user with name as "festival"?

Tags: bash, scripts

Have tried this script out of abs-guide (downloaded in this galaxy somewhere...) :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5952973/

It was written by Mendel Cooper.

Now on my machine an user pops up with name "festival" - what or who is that ?

Comment: ah, now have read that "festival" is something regarding "speech'n audio" - also for "audio-addicted people" - have uninstalled it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably created when you installed `festival - General multi-lingual speech synthesis system`.

Homework?

Note that the script could be replaced by `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`

# Discussion:
 # ------------------
 # How is it that an ordinary user, or a script run by same,
 # can read /etc/passwd? (Hint: Check the /etc/passwd file permissions.)
 # Is this a security hole? Why or why not?

Consider: How do programs convert from UID numbers to usernames? See `man 5 passwd`, `man getpwent`.